# Xdebug 3.1.1 doesn't show variables except $_COOKIE, $_GET, $_REQUEST, $_SERVER

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, xdebug-3

I use PHP 7.4.26 with Xdebug 3.1.1, Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) and PhpStorm as a client.

In the xdebug log file I see that any variable I use in my PHP script come as 'uninitialized'

So whatever my script contains I receive only 4 variables `$_COOKIE`, `$_GET`, `$_REQUEST`, `$_SERVER`.

My Xdebug settings:

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.discover_client_host = false
xdebug.client_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port = 9000
xdebug.log=/xdebug.log
```

Comment: 1) Is this a CLI script debug or a web page? 2) Make a new file with basic logic where each command is on separate line, like `<?php $a = 1; $b = 3; $c = $a + $b; echo "Result: $a\n";` try to debug it -- will it work here? 3) Enable Xdebug logging (which I see you have already), try to debug this test script and see what the log will say (share it). 4) Show a screenshot of what you see as well (that can give some hints; maybe it's some confusion/misunderstanding here etc.)

Comment: 1) This is a web page
2) No
3) Here my log https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kDEFo0H-SI0d6R_jOEMaeXMdNBfbB3dpZz3cNJyZMSI/edit?usp=sharing
4) Here several screenshots https://i.imgur.com/Z46w6fl.png https://i.imgur.com/VXT3TZv.png https://i.imgur.com/UK3MtmG.png https://i.imgur.com/NPH0Hwo.png

Comment: So .. what happens next? From what I see the breakpoint was resolved just fine (line #4) in the right script (`/var/www/html/index.php`). It stopped at line #2 as you must have "Break at first line in PHP scripts" option enabled. So far everything is good on your screenshots -- I see nothing wrong at all. **What happens next when you do "Step over" to move to the next line?** Try making a screencast/video (there are many free tools) that will show the whole process of the whole screen.

Comment: So far I do not see any `uninitialized` anywhere on your screenshots. I see it in the log at line #63 -- the response for command #19. But that's absolutely expected -- while execution is stopped at line #2 (as per your screenshot) those `$a`, `$b` and `$c ` and not yet initialized at that point. `$a` will become known/initialized only when `$a = 1;` will be actually executed.